# Viewing history of echo'd text on terminal

Tags: terminal, putty, session

I detached gits head using `git checkout 4037ec1702bd2fa6a5a15f7413f4ccccb59d356e .` and lost all my [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023690/return-to-working-git-version-after-checking-out-branch).

I still have the terminal open.  Not that long ago, I did a `git diff`, so my changes were all echo'd to the terminal.  I can only scroll so far up, however, and just can view the very end of the export.

Is there any way I can view what was earlier echo'd to the terminal?  As stated, I still have the original session.

Comment: try, `history | grep "echo" `

Comment: That will just display the last time I typed in "echo".  I am trying to actually see what was displayed on the screen, but the putty terminal doesn't allow me to scroll up that far.

Comment: Don't think you can do it, but you can [increase the size of the scrollback](https://superuser.com/questions/129868/increase-scrollback-buffer-in-putty) buffer to prevent problems next time.

Comment: `git`and the system should have logging facilities enabled by default. Check in `/var/log` and the system journal with `journalctl -b`(assuming you're using a systemd-based OS). If you're lucky, the important output was logged.

Comment: @Mioriin  Yes, I am using Centos7.  What should I be looking for in the logs?  Is the output to the screen actually logged?

Comment: @RoVo.  Yeah, I see I can do so for next time (hopefully there isn't a next time!)

Comment: cant you execute the same command echo'd in history?